# Paypal Subscription Details Api is giving "Active" status although total cycles complete is 0

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working with paypal subscription api v1. When an user subscribe to one of my plans on my website, the subscription_id is sent to my server. There I check the status and next billing date using the subscription details api to give the user some value. But when the user subscribes and my server checks for the status, the response it is getting is confusing. The response json is given below:

```
{'status': 'ACTIVE', 
'status_update_time': '2019-11-13T09:36:35Z', 
'id': '***', 
'plan_id': '***', 
'start_time': '2019-11-12T16:00:00Z', 
'quantity': '1', 
'shipping_amount': {'currency_code': 'USD', 'value': '0.0'}, 
'subscriber': {'name': **, 'email_address': '***', 'shipping_address': **}, 
'billing_info': {
  'outstanding_balance': {'currency_code': 'USD', 'value': '0.0'}, 
  'cycle_executions': [{
    'tenure_type': 'REGULAR', 
    'sequence': 1, 
    'cycles_completed': 0, 
    'cycles_remaining': 0, 
    'current_pricing_scheme_version': 1, 
    'total_cycles': 0
  }], 
  'next_billing_time': '2019-11-13T09:36:33Z', 
  'failed_payments_count': 0
}, 
'create_time': '2019-11-13T09:35:46Z', 
'update_time': '2019-11-13T09:36:35Z',
```

Here you can see that the status is active but the next_billing_time is less than the status_update_time. And also no payment cycle is completed. Why paypal is behaving like this? I think the status should not be "ACTIVE" if the cycle is not complete. So why is it giving active status?